# rails form checkbox array/hash value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I create a checkbox that stores a hash, so that when I retrieve the value in params array I get a hash.

Comment: Ah, sorry I am kinda new,  didnt realize that feature was available. Will do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller `@hash = [your hash code]`

In your view: `<% check_box_tag 'name', @hash %>`

Use the other view helpers if you want to make it part of a form http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#M002256 and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

EDIT: Based on the comments below

You'll need to do things a little differently.
Build your checkbox like this:
`<%= check_box :search, "conditions", {:onclick => "refreshResults(this);"}, "#{result.to_s}=#{option.to_s}" %>`

This will produce checkboxes where `value="city=blah blah"`, when you process this in rails do:

```
search = {}
conditions.each do |c|
    c.split('=').each{|k,v| search[k] = v}
end
```

You can then use your search hash to filter.

Comment: well when I do this..
<% result.each do |result, result_options|%> 
<% result_options.each do |option, count| %>
                <%= f.check_box "facet", {result => option}%>
              <% end  %>
<%end %>

I get..

<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="search[facet]" id="search_facet" article_tag="Energy">
the value is still 1

Comment: Try `check_box :search, :facet, {}, hash` Do not use the f.check_box and match :search to whatever the part before the `[]` in the `name="name[]"` is

Comment: Thanks.
Here is what I get

<input type="checkbox" value="article_tagEnergy" onclick="refreshResults(this);" name="search[conditions]" id="search_conditions">

From..
 <%= check_box :search, "conditions", {:onclick => "refreshResults(this);"}, {result => option}  %>

Instead of a hash the {result => option} is producing article_tagEnergy.In my controller I am hoping to get 
params[:search][:conditions] = {{articletag => Energy}, {city => "xxx"}}

Comment: AH! When i hear 'hash' I think of a 'hash code' (MD5, SHA1, etc). What is it you want in the checkbox value EXACTLY? The only thing you can put in there are effectively strings. You'll need to do some post processing to determine it. I'm going to add another answer to format this better.

Comment: Well I thought you could send arrays and hashes in params?
I want something like this in my search model.
params = {
      :controller => 'search',
      :action => 'set_search',
      :conditions => {:city => [:x, :y], :tag => [a, b]}
       :models => {[abc], [dddd]}
      }
is that possible? I
    }

Comment: Doing that causes the params[:conditions] to be "0" in the controller.Since there are multiple checkboxes with conditions name? May be today isn't my day, this should not be this hard :).. here is my entire view.Look at line 62. http://pastie.org/992456

I am trying to create check boxes so that when a user click on article_tag facet, I retrievve records for those facets only, user might select multiple facets that translate into multiple conditions.